# Dql query to find all the attributes

Tags: d, documentum

I need a full dql query to find all the attributes (single and Repeating) for the documents. I haven't tried any query.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to clarify your problem description and if possible add some code. Also tell us what you tried so far. With that little information I doubt anybody can help you. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

You can select all attributes for object type using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT attr_name, attr_type, attr_repeating, attr_length FROM dm_type WHERE name = 'dm_document' ORDER BY attr_name
```

Where you replace `dm_document` by your target object type name and

- `attr_name` contains attribute name
- `attr_type` defines attribute type (*0* - Boolean, *1* - Integer, *2* - String, *3* - ID, *4* - Time, *5* - Double)
- `attr_repeating` indicates whether the attribute is repeating or not
- `attr_length` defines size of String based attributes

If you want only attributes for that object type and not ones inherited from super type then you can select them by this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r_object_id, attr_name, attr_type, attr_repeating, attr_length, i_position, start_pos FROM dm_type WHERE name = 'dm_document' AND i_position < -start_pos ORDER BY attr_name ENABLE(ROW_BASED)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a "describe " to get information.

You should also investigate the views underneath if you're querying from non-dql application.